# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'add_time_slot' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_time_slot/(?P<turf_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django, template-inheritance

I getting an error while doing python django project.

**The error**:

```
'NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'add_time_slot' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_time_slot/(?P<turf_id>[0-9]+)/\\Z']'. 
Several things i tried but nothing works please help me...
```

## view.py

```
def add_time_slot(request, turf_id):
    turf = Venue.objects.get(pk=turf_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TimeSlotForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            timeslot = form.save(commit=False)
            timeslot.turf = turf
            timeslot.save()
            return redirect('add_time_slot', turf_id=turf_id)
    else:
        form = TimeSlotForm()
    return render(request, 'add_time_slot.html', {'form': form, 'turf': turf})
```

## url.py

```
path('add_time_slot/<int:turf_id>/', views.add_time_slot, name='add_time_slot'),
```

## html

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_time_slot' turf_id %}">Add Time Slots</a>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The encountered error suggests that the `turf_id` argument provided to the `{% url 'add_time_slot' turf_id %}` template tag is either empty or invalid. To troubleshoot, verify that `turf_id` is a valid variable within your template. Confirm its presence in the context by checking the view responsible for rendering the template. The view should return a render statement similar to the one below:

```py
return render(request, 'html_raising_no_reverse_match.html', {'turf_id': turf.pk})
```

Ensure that the `turf_id` is correctly passed to the template context so that it can be utilised in generating the URL. This verification step should help resolve the issue with the reverse match error.

Additionally, in your view, you might want to add some error handling for the case when the `Venue` with the specified turf_id is not found. If the `Venue` does not exist, it could result in a `DoesNotExist` exception. Using `turf = get_object_or_404(Venue, pk=turf_id)` instead of `turf = Venue.objects.get(pk=turf_id)` helps to handle the case when the specified `Venue` does not exist, returning a `404` response instead of raising a `DoesNotExist` exception.